# Can banks charge a lower interest rate for loans than for their fixed term savings account and still make profit?

Tags: loans, banking, interest-rate, profitability, certificate-of-deposit

A friend of mine got a loan of 1,000,000 at an interest rate of 10.6% per year for three years and then deposited that 1 million at 3-year fixed-term non-accessible savings account with a return interest rate of 12% per year at the **same** bank. In the short term, at the end of each year, he will have paid (106,000 + 333,333) = 439,333 and received back the 12% from the savings account which amounts to 120,000.

That means that at the end of the three-year period he will have received 360,000 in interest payments and the 1,000,000 back totaling 1,360,000 and will have paid 1,318,000(439,333*3) therefore making a profit of 1.4% per year.

How is that possible? Why would the bank lend out money at a lower rate than they're paying their depositors for it? Why would the bank intentionally incur a loss? Did I miss something?

Edit: The country is Egypt, the currency is Egyptian pounds, and the bank is NBE

**Edit 2**: Sorry, turns out the bank is **Banque Misr** not NBE

**Edit 3**: By fixed-term non-accessible savings account I meant **Certificate of Deposit**

Comment: This is probably not actually happening

Comment: You’ll need to tell us what country it is, what currency it is, and what bank it is, if you want to get any kind of a reasoned answer.

Comment: @JakeFreeman  I am 100% sure it is, I had a look at his account statements and all the numbers are correct. One possibility would be that bank could have made a mistake or maybe they only allow a small percentage of people to take a loan a lower interest rate than they charge for savings account to increase their cash flow and lend out the net amount of money they get received by the end of the first year (439,333 - 120,000= 319333)  at normal/higher rates?

Comment: @MikeScott The country is Egypt, the currency is Egyptian pounds, and the bank is NBE

Comment: Is the loan at.a fixed interest rate or just the savings account. If the loan is a variable rate loan then perhaps the bank has reason to expect that interest rates will increase over the next 3 years.

Comment: Have you checked the bank's published interest rates for both deposits and loans? NBE's English language site doesn't carry such information, so I can't check. Call them up and ask about a loan and/or deposit yourself. Also is your friend suggesting that you give him money so that he can do the same for you?

Comment: Were the loan and the savings account started at the same time, or was there separation in time that happened to line up with a change in central bank outlook? I also see that the 1MM loan is repaid over the term where the savings principal is repaid at year 3.  If the local inflation rate is high (and only going by market rate interest 10%-12%, it seems likely) that's a risk borne by the investor not the bank.

Comment: @RobertLongson It's fixed interest rate loan for a fixed duration of 3 years

Comment: @DJClayworth Sorry turns out the bank my friend used was Banque Misr and not NBE, and this was 6 months ago, so I presume the rates have changed since then

Comment: @user662852 They were both started within 2/3 days of each other, and they're both paid over term

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. An unsecured loan for short term can't be lower than term deposits.

If its genuine, it could be there is a huge loan sanction fees that makes up for difference... or this was done at different times and the rates went up.... if this was a 20 year loan at variable interest rates, its possible in some years for something like this to happen...

If this is some friend on internet, it could be a scam.

Comment: I believe that it is a secured loan as my friend has most of their money about > 1.5 M (EGP) with the same bank. The loan was taken on March 2020, and a few days after received the money, he deposited the whole amount into a certificate of deposit with a return of 12% for three years. The loan was a 3-year fixed interest loan, at an interest rate of 10.6% and no other fees.


> If this is some friend on internet, it could be a scam.

haha, he's not, he's a close childhood friend dw